# How to find src value using javascript in any HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, variables

open tag audio id="song"
source id="file-path" src="media/Kaattumalli.mp3" type="audio/mp3"
audio close tag

I tried many ways to find the solution. But, I failed to take src value into a javascript variable. Anyone Know the trick to solve the problem. Please let me know the trick.
How to take the src file name and store the value in a variable using javascript. Please any help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use id of the audio tag to get the element and then you can get attributes from the tag using that element

```
const audio = document.getElementById("file-path")
const audioSrc = audio.src;
console.log(audioSrc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   var a = document.getElementById("song");
   var source = a.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
   var src = source.getAttribute('src');
   console.log(src);
</script>
```